# Does losing rep also make you lose previously earned privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, privileges

Say a user is plugging along the SO site with 2010 rep which means he has recently acquired the privilege to edit questions and answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges.

Now suppose this user makes a few bad answers resulting in downvotes which brings his rep down to 1998. Does he then lose the edit privilege?

What about lower privileges like downvoting, which only requires 125 rep and is awarded to relatively new users?